# Error when binding a DataGridView to a BindingNavigator

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-ce

I have the following small *child* form:

[image]

To link the controls to my database table I've so far got the following.

I've tried to link the datagridview to the navigator in a similar way I'd link a textbox to the navigator - what is the correct syntax to join these controls?

```
    public SqlCeConnection conn = new SqlCeConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["WindFormAppRevisionHelper.Properties.Settings.DefinitionsDBConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
    BindingSource rawtableBindingSource = new BindingSource();


    public uxFormDatabase()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        fillTheDGVusingAdapter();
    }

    public void fillTheDGVusingAdapter()
    {

        SqlCeDataAdapter da = new SqlCeDataAdapter(new SqlCeCommand("Select * From tb_Definitions", conn));
        DataSet ds = new DataSet("DGVdata");
        ds.Tables.Add("rawTable");
        da.Fill(ds.Tables["rawTable"]);

        uxDGVtable.DataSource = ds.Tables["rawTable"];

        rawtableBindingSource.DataSource = ds.Tables["rawTable"];
        uxrawdataBindingNavigator.BindingSource = this.rawtableBindingSource;

         //PROBLEM WITH THE FOLLOWING LINE
        uxDGVtable.DataSource = DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", uxrawdataBindingNavigator, "Item_Id", true));

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a little unclear what you are doing, because 3 lines earlier, you already set the DataSource of the uxDGVtable control.

Try just using the same BindingSource the Navigator is using:

```
// uxDGVtable.DataSource = ds.Tables["rawTable"];
uxDGVtable.DataSource = this.rawtableBindingSource;
```

Comment: ok - will this then mean that any buttons on the navigator and the datagridview will all be linked upto the database table i.e any changes made via these controls will be saved to the database?

Comment: @whytheq Yes, using the same binding source for the grid and the navigator will link them together.  It won't automatically save the data though, that you still have to do yourself through a proper update call.

Comment: lol...just experimenting with the save before reading your comment and hitting more problems! (I had the first iteration of this winForm working ok but I'm trying to code this new version without using the wizards to create datasets and binding for me ... for a newbie like me it is quite painful but hopefully worthwhile). I will post the save problem as a new question

Comment: ...I've added a further question in connection with the same form: [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11492794/what-is-required-to-refresh-bound-data-displayed-on-winform)